# regex: match two /'s back from end of line

Tags: regex, awk

I have a file of file paths. The depth of the directories is of various lengths and path names. I'd like to match two directories backwards (two /'s) and delete the match, creating a new file with the results.

eg:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/output_job3344.xml
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/otherfile.txt
```

the result would be:

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
```

I tried something like this:

```
awk -F'/*./.*$' '{print $0}' deep.list
```

but that didn't work out.

Comment: Its not really a duplicate but sure.  This question generated better answers too so in my opinion this is providing additional useful info. I searched for the solution before posting for at least 10 minutes without luck.   "Similar" should be an option along with "duplicate".

Comment: I wouldn't say duplicate since the answer is not the same. I agree it's similar, and one could study the answer to one and learn how to solve the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your idea is smart**, but needs a few corrections. Here's how you probably meant it:

```
awk -F'[^/]*/[^/]*$' '{print $1}' deep.list
```

**Explanation:**

First thing, you probably misspelled `.*` as `*.`.

Then, the `*` modifier is *greedy*, therefore you need to take care it doesn't match more than you intended! The solution is simple, albeit slightly less readable: use `[^/]*` instead of `.*`. This way you match any characters except `/`.

Lastly, `$0` represents the entire line, which hasn't been altered in the slightest by specifying a specially crafted custom field separator. In this case you want to print the first field instead: `$1`.

---

Here's a different approach than the two [answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/879504/sed-how-to-how-to-extract-the-last-two-or-any-number-directories-from-a-path) linked by [@ender.qa](https://serverfault.com/users/470077/ender-qa):

```
awk '{gsub("[^/]+/[^/]+$","");print}' deep.list
```

And one employing a loop:

```
awk -F/ '{for(i=1;i<=NF-2;i++){printf "%s/",$i}; print ""}' deep.list
```

---

The substitution method is more easily implemented in Perl:

```
perl -lape 's"[^/]+/[^/]+$""' deep.list
```

or sed:

```
sed -E 's"[^/]+/[^/]+$""' deep.list
```

Comment: Thank you simlev.  I like how you did it with sed and is what I ended up using.